# Cache Asp.Net doesn't exist Asp.Net 5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, caching, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I am using Asp.net 5 and MVC 6 targeting the .Net framework 4.5.2
I want to use the following code:

```
Cache["test"] = "test";
```

or

```
HttpContext.Cache["test"] = "test";
```

But both get the following error that Cache doesn't exist in this context.
What am I missing??

**Edit:**

As answered below, you can cache using the IMemoryCache interface by injecting it into your controller. This seems to be new in asp.net 5 RC1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I cache objects in ASP.NET MVC?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/445050/how-can-i-cache-objects-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Where do you access the cache?

Comment: I could not replicate it. `public ActionResult Index() {HttpContext.Cache["Name"] = 123; var value = HttpContext.Cache["Name"]; return View();}` Could you create a new ASP.Net project and try again?

Comment: Yes I created a new project it still says that HttpContext doesn't contain a definition for Cache, thats very strange, do I have to add some packages or directives?

Comment: try `HttpRuntime.Cache`?

Comment: Ok, if I use cache as well as session in asp.net 4 it works. But somehow this doesn't work in Asp.net 5

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269072/how-to-cache-resources-in-mvc-6 maybe this will help?

Comment: Try `Context.HttpContext.Cache.Get("Name");` or `Context.HttpContext.Cache.Insert("Name", values);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MVC 6, you can cache using the `IMemoryCache` interface by injecting it into your controller.

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Caching.Memory;

public class HomeController
{
    private readonly IMemoryCache _cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        if (cache == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("cache");
        _cache = cache;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Get an item from the cache
        string key = "test";
        object value;
        if (_cache.TryGetValue(key, out value))
        {
            // Reload the value here from wherever
            // you need to get it from
            value = "test";

            _cache.Set(key, value);
        }

        // Do something with the value

        return View();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Update your `startup.cs` to have this inside `ConfigureServices`:

```
services.AddCaching();
```

Then update the controller to have a dependency of `IMemoryCache`:

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    private IMemoryCache cache;

    public HomeController(IMemoryCache cache)
    {
        this.cache = cache;
    }
```

Then you can use it in your actions like:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        // Set Cache
        var myList = new List<string>();
        myList.Add("lorem");
        this.cache.Set("MyKey", myList, new MemoryCacheEntryOptions());
        return View();
    }
```

And

```
    public IActionResult About()
    {
        ViewData["Message"] = "Your application description page.";

        // Read cache
        var myList= this.cache.Get("MyKey");

        // Use value

        return View();
    }
```

Much [more detail](http://dotnet.today/en/aspnet5-vnext/fundamentals/caching.html) on `MemoryCache` on dotnet.today.