# How to cache with EFCore in ASP.NET Core

Tags: asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I have a select query on a table which gives the last searches on the website.

This is for inspiration, and does not require to be updated for every page call, therefore I would like to cache these searches as it begins to show some performances impact.

My website uses ASP.NET Core and EFCore.

I believe there is no built-in way to do that on a single line. 
**What would be the best approach?**

**I am thinking about updating every 10 minutes the 300 last searches in memory** and pick few of them randomly.

Up to now I have found these two options which I could use:

1. Raw cache method for ASP.Net Core
   [How to cache resources in Asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269072/how-to-cache-resources-in-asp-net-core)
2. EFCore open-source extension, which includes much more than just caching
   http://entityframework-plus.net/

---

The solution I am using:

```
in startup.cs:
services.AddMemoryCache();


in view/controller:
var LAST_SEARCHS_COUNT = 5;
var lastSearchs = await Cache.GetOrCreateAsync<List<Search>>("LAST_SEARCHS"
    ,(k)=> {
        k.AbsoluteExpirationRelativeToNow = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(10);
        return (from s in DbContext.Searchs
                orderby s.CreationTime descending
                select s).Take(LAST_SEARCHS_COUNT * 40).ToListAsync();
    });
```

The impact is quite significant, with calls count divided by more than 100:

[image: Impact of changes...]

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/distributed

Comment: Thanks for the link, that extends my solution number 1

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Response Caching](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/response)

```
[ResponseCache(VaryByHeader = "User-Agent", Duration = 30)]
public IActionResult About2()
{
```

Also [Response Caching Middleware](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/performance/caching/middleware)

You could also keep a static instance of the DataContext and make sure change tracking is enabled. That will keep it in memory to track changes. It might get slow though.

Comment: It is not fitting my case because I prefer to have a different random result for each request of a same user, and I need it only for a partial view (however this looks like a nice solution that I might use for other cases with more "static" content), thanks anyway!

Comment: `Responses containing content for authenticated clients must be marked as not cacheable to prevent the middleware from storing and serving those responses.` Oops...  :)