# ViewData for _Layout - ActionFilter, ViewComponent or something else?

Tags: asp.net-core-2.0, razor-pages

What's best practice for loading ViewData for _Layout file?
ActionFilter, ViewComponent or something else?

I need to load Site name, default meta keywords, description, facebook link (in header & footer), footer contacts info.

I would like to avoid multiple SQL querys for same query

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately what you are asking, I believe, is how do I preserve data from one request to the next.

There are many approaches that each have trade-offs.  No one approach is best for all circumstances.  Some of those approaches are:

1) Store the information in cache as shown here [How to cache resources in Asp.net core?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28269072/how-to-cache-resources-in-asp-net-core).

2) Store it in session.

3) If the information were small you could store it in a cookie. But the info you mention would likely better fit option 1 or option 2.

Comment: Actually I was asking how to set ViewData for _Layout without Controller. For now I implemented IActionFilter which sets ViewData like facebook link or contacts from database